# sklearn Linear Regression on 2d scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

I'm having a problem performing the sklearn Linear Regression on a 2d scatter in tuple form. I have my data generated from text from a csv file, i.e., using `np.genfromtxt`

Here is a fully operational part of my code:

Importing modules:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

from sklearn import linear_model
```

The dataset in tuple form:

```
bpt_class_sey, logLOIII_blue_sey, logLOIII_red_sey, logOII_OIII_sey = np.genfromtxt('/Users/iMacHome/Downloads/seyfert_LOIII_LOGOIIOIII.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```

The regression:

```
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

regr.fit(logLOIII_blue_sey, logOII_OIII_sey)
```

The regression plot:

```
axScatter.plot(logLOIII_blue_sey, regr.predict(logLOIII_blue_sey), color='blue',linewidth=3)
```

Now, I receive the following error:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I'm wondering if anyone would know how to quickly solve this minor problem. I have looked as much as I can online but nothing explains why this happens/possible solutions or even a whole new way of performing a statistically reliable linear regression for a dataset in the format I have. The full code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

from sklearn import datasets, linear_model

bpt_class_comp, logLOIII_blue_comp, logLOIII_red_comp, logOII_OIII_comp = np.genfromtxt('/Users/iMacHome/Downloads/composite_LOIII_LOGOIIOIII.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
bpt_class_sf, logLOIII_blue_sf, logLOIII_red_sf, logOII_OIII_sf         = np.genfromtxt('/Users/iMacHome/Downloads/starforming_LOIII_LOGOIIOIII.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
bpt_class_sey, logLOIII_blue_sey, logLOIII_red_sey, logOII_OIII_sey     = np.genfromtxt('/Users/iMacHome/Downloads/seyfert_LOIII_LOGOIIOIII.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

regr.fit(logLOIII_blue_sey, logOII_OIII_sey)

fig = plt.figure(132)

axScatter = fig.add_subplot(131)
axScatter.set_ylabel(r'$\mathrm{log([OII]/[OIII])}$', fontsize='medium')
axScatter.set_xlabel(r'$\mathrm{log[}L\mathrm{_{[OIII]}\ (erg\ {s^{-1}})]}$', fontsize='medium')
axScatter.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.0)
axScatter.set_xlim(39, 44)
axScatter.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10)
axScatter.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=10)
axScatter.xaxis.labelpad = 10
axScatter.scatter(logLOIII_blue_sey, logOII_OIII_sey, marker="o", c='0.1',s=15,lw=1)
axScatter.scatter(logLOIII_blue_comp, logOII_OIII_comp, marker="o", c='#6633ff',s=15,lw=1)
axScatter.scatter(logLOIII_blue_sf, logOII_OIII_sf, marker="o", c='0.7',s=15,lw=1)

axScatter.plot([logLOIII_blue_sey, regr.predict(logLOIII_blue_sey)], color='blue',linewidth=3)

axScatter = fig.add_subplot(132)
#axScatter.set_ylabel(r'$\mathrm{log([OII]/[OIII])}$', fontsize='medium')
axScatter.set_xlabel(r'$\mathrm{log[}L\mathrm{_{[OIII]} (erg {s^{-1}})]}$', fontsize='medium')
axScatter.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.0)
axScatter.set_xlim(39, 44)
axScatter.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10)
axScatter.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=10)
axScatter.xaxis.labelpad = 10
axScatter.scatter(logLOIII_red_sey, logOII_OIII_sey, marker="o", c='0.1',s=15,lw=1)
axScatter.scatter(logLOIII_red_comp, logOII_OIII_comp, marker="o", c='#6633ff',s=15,lw=1)
axScatter.scatter(logLOIII_red_sf, logOII_OIII_sf, marker="o", c='0.7',s=15,lw=1)

axHistogram = fig.add_subplot(133)

plt.show()
```

As an example, using:

```
print logLOIII_blue_sey
```

Yields:

```
[ 42.30730188  42.67215043  42.15924954  41.61370469  41.94149606
  41.22327958  42.15549254  42.07837228  41.43995205  41.44106463]

print logLOIII_blue_sey

[ -0.05883232 -0.10934038 -0.10249362  0.71041126  0.12462513  0.69641850
   0.11334571         nan -0.07256197  0.72781828  0.02585652  0.70823414]
```

Comment: Michael, while it may sound annoying, StackOverflow encourages members to post an MCVE ( a **M**inimum-**C**omplete-**V**erifiable-**E**xample of code ), which means you ought to complete the OP with the full code, not just a few SLOC-excerpts, and also ( perhaps as a sub-sample ) your data-file, that the code was designed to work with. Would be great if you re-consider this StackOverflow Policy and kindly complete your post.

Comment: Not a problem at all. I  didn't want to overload the question with code. I think the problem comes from the 'nan' within the logLOIII_blue_sey tuple

Comment: Great. Just check, what is your problem-domain common sanity for NaN(s) & you are done, right?

Comment: Tried the code with new csv with the NaN removed, it still isn't responding well to the tuple.

Comment: I, and I'm sure many others, sincerely appreciate your willingness to update your question and attempt to make a MCVE. However, what you have here is not yet **M**inimum nor **C**omplete, because it a) has a lot of extra stuff such as scatter calls that are irrelevant to the question, and b) it requires ingestion of data inaccessible to us.  An even better question MCVE could reproduce your error with fake data and a minimum of code lines.  Yes, it means *making a brand new example*.  Don't be afraid of doing that - sometimes it helps you with your bug before you even post it.

Comment: And as to the actual question - which line gives you that error?